# Implode starting from key 1

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I got an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => shop [1] => kids [2] => shorts )
```

Now I want all the values `implode` seperated with a slash `/`. BUT I want to pass the first key, `[0]`.

Doing an `implode()` on the above will result in:

```
shop/kids/shorts
```

But I want this result:

```
kids/shorts
```

Is this possible? I can't find anything for the `implode()` function to start from a specific key or ignore the first `array entries`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_shift`](http://www.php.net/array_shift) before the implode:

```
array_shift($array);
$data = implode('/', $array);
```

Comment: Wow, look how easy the answer is. Thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, of course `array_shift()` returns the shifted element and manipulates the input array

Comment: @kingkero no worries mate, being inactive doesn't mean it wont be accepted. Everyone needs sleep :)